# AVAssest initialisation with url from youtube adaptive formats is taking time to load video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avasset

*AVasset is taking time to load(For only video formats). But simple formats is not taking time(Merged video and audio). The issue was even reproduced in AVPlayer(url: URL(string:*The url retrieved from YouTube api*/ as! String)!)*

```
func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl:URL, audioUrl:URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> (Void))
    {  
       let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

        let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl) //Here is the issue
        let key = "playable"
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            aVideoAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [key], completionHandler: {
                let status = aVideoAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: key, error: nil)
                if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {

                    let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)
                    aAudioAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [key], completionHandler: {
                        let status1 = aAudioAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: key, error: nil)
                        if status1 == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {

                            mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!)
                            mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!)

                            let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
                            let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]

                            do{
                                try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

                                try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aAudioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
                            } catch{

                            }

                            totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

                            let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
                            mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

                            mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280,height: 720)

                            self.mixComposition = mixComposition
                            _ = completion(true)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: merged audio and video is very likely to be loading from the disk, the youtube video will need to be at least part downloaded to play. This then depends on your network speed, usage etc

Comment: Only video is also taking time. If I load already merged url than it is not taking time